# Check if UDP port is opened in Perl

Tags: perl, udp

I need to check if remote UDP port is opened. My part of code is:

```
sub scanUDP {
    my $address = shift;
    my $port = shift;
    my $udpSocket = new IO::Socket::INET (
                                        PeerAddr => $address,
                                        PeerPort => $port,
                                        Proto => 'udp',
                                        ) or return 0;
    $udpSocket -> send ('hello', 0);
    #........SOME CODE.............
    return 1;
}
```

`..SOME CODE..` should check if I received ICMP packets "Host unreached" or "Port unreached" to check if port is opened. But how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code that works for me:

```
sub scanUDP {
    my $address = shift;
    my $port = shift;
    my $socket = new IO::Socket::INET (
                                        PeerAddr => $address,
                                        PeerPort => $port,
                                        Proto => 'udp',
                                        ) or return 0;
    $socket -> send('Hello',0);
    my $select = new IO::Select();
    $select -> add($socket);
    my @socket = $select -> can_read(1);
    if (@socket == 1) {
        $socket -> recv(my $temp, 1, 0) or return 0;
        return 1;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really get an ICMP unreachable back you will receive the error with a later send call (unless you peer is localhost, than you might get it with the first one already). But there is no guarantee that you will get an ICMP unreachable back at all, because either ICMP or the UDP itself might be filtered by a firewall.

It looks like it will not report the problem on windows this way, but you can use recv there instead of send (works on UNIX too). The error code is probably something specific to windows, ECONNREFUSED works only on UNIX:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use IO::Socket::INET;

my $cl = IO::Socket::INET->new(
    PeerAddr => '192.168.122.42:12345', # definitly rejecting
    Proto => 'udp',
);
$cl->send('foo') or die "send failed: $!"; # first send will succeed
# wait some time to receive ICMP unreachable
sleep(1);
$cl->blocking(0);
if ( ! $cl->recv( my $buf,0)) {
    # will get ECONNREFUSED on UNIX, on Win the code is different
    warn "error $!" if ! $!{EAGAIN};
}
```

Comment: Try another send call a while later - if it fails with ECONNREFUSED you got an ICMP unreachable in the mean time.

Comment: You will not get any ICMP packet by requesting for UDP. You will certainly not get a ECONNREFUSED, as there is no connection in the streaming sense.

Comment: @LeonTimmermans: Yes you will, because the socket is connected. Don't believe me? Check http://pastebin.com/kxqnfQ9q - there you find the code, the strace, the tcpdump.

Comment: Interesting. It's not listed in Linux's send/sendto documentation, and only vaguely mentioned in the udp manpage. POSIX doesn't seem to describe it either, though Alan Cox claims it's [RFC1122 compliant](http://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0002.3/0709.html)

Comment: Yes, but it is documented in the sendto man-page on OpenBSD and the behavior their is the same.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Your code from http://pastebin.com/kxqnfQ9q doesn't print anything on my computer. Windows 7, Strawberry Perl 5.18.2

Comment: It might be that either the Windows firewall blocks the ICMP unreachable or the peer does not send one (did you check with a packet sniffer?). It might also be that Windows Network stack behaves differently from UNIX.

Comment: It looks like it will not report the issue on windows with the next send(to), but only with recv. recv works on UNIX too. See code in answer.

Comment: I get "A non-blocking socket operation could not be completed immediately" error after running your code. @SteffenUllrich

Comment: @user23791: this is same as EWOULDBLOCK. In this case you probably did not get the the ICMP unreachable. Did you check with a packet sniffer that you receive it at all?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Yes, I receive ICMP "Port unreachable" packet.

Comment: Please try against a port on localhost to make sure, that the firewall does not filter the ICMP. I've tested the code with strawberry perl 5.18.1 on windows 7 against localhost and get error 10054, e.g. WSAECONNRESET "Connection reset by peer". If I try it against my router I first got the error you described, but after switching off the firewall on Windows I got also WSAECONNRESET.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I get "A non-blocking socket operation could not be completed immediately" even if I try to check localhost's port or if I turn Windows firewall off.

Comment: Then I don't know. Like I said, this code is running for me on Win7 with strawberry perl 5.18.1.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Well, your http://pastebin.com/kxqnfQ9q example doesn't work on Xubuntu 11.10 neither. I verified that I receive ICMP "unreachable" packages.

Comment: Strange. I've tried it on Ubuntu 10.04, 12.04, 13.10, Win7, OpenBSD 4.6, 5.3 and 5.5. Have you tried with localhost as target?

Answer (score 1):

Generally you can't. UDP does not have a connected state, so it is in no way required to send you any reply to the packet you sent. And that's even when ignoring package loss. You may get a positive reply if you sent a valid request in whatever protocol you're accessing and the remote port is open, but the absence of such a reply can not be used to make any conclusions.

Comment: Exactly. You need to send some data to the server's application listening on that port, and see if you get a response back. You cannot use tools like telnet to check connectivity to a UDP listening port.